# Android: how to create new instance of childactivity from SingleTask TabActivity's onNewIntent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabactivity

I have following flow in normal situation

H (`homeactivity`) - T(`TabActivity`)- L (`Activity` class containing list) - D (`DescriptionActivity`)

If pushnotification comes it will traverse to D without any click (refreshing associated data for each activity in background).

But as T is `singleTask`, (if the app is minimized at the time of push notification) its (T) `onNewIntent` is called and L and D does not get refreshed

Please help me

- Ronny